# Is it possible to override a clock function so I could change its hours?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, clock

I'm designing a small browser project where you pick a city from the list and it presents you with the current time in city of your choice. 
Although I've come across a problem. 
The code only shows the correct time for a brief moment and then returns to the original UTC Standard time.  The problem comes up at the "setTimeout" bit. Is there a possibility to override this? By adding clearTimeout perhaps?

```js
function utcStandard(offset) {
  var date = new Date();
  var hh = date.getUTCHours();
  var mm = date.getUTCMinutes();
  var ss = date.getUTCSeconds();
  if (offset != undefined) {
    hh += offset
  };
  hh = checkTime(hh);
  mm = checkTime(mm);
  ss = checkTime(ss);
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
    hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
  var t = setTimeout(utcStandard, 500);

  function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
      i = "0" + i
    };
    return i;
  }
}
```

I decided to add the function to each item in the HTML list. For example.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="utcStandard(1)">Amsterdam</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You will need to cancel the timeout so the function with the old param doesn’t recursively calls itself.

Comment: You can use `setTimeout(utcStandard,bind(this, offset), 500)` to pass the `offset` to the new call to `utcStandard`.

Comment: just have to pass in the `offset`: `setTimeout(() => utcStandard(offset), 500);`

Comment: Note that time zone offsets can have partial numbers of hours...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Good call. I changed my solution to minutes

Answer (score 0):

Like this - it is shorter and uses UTC where it is needed

I changed to minutes so you can have 5:30 for India for example

I did not consider DST for now

```js
const pad = (num) => ("0"+num).slice(-2);
let t;
let curOffset = 0;

const reset = (offset) => { 
  clearInterval(t);
  curOffset = offset ? offset : curOffset;  
  t = setInterval(utcStandard,500);
  return false;
};

const utcStandard = () => {
  var date = new Date(new Date().toUTCString().substr(0, 25))
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+curOffset);
  const hh = pad(date.getHours());
  const mm = pad(date.getMinutes());
  const ss = pad(date.getSeconds());
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "" + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
};
reset(0);
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return reset(60)">Amsterdam</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return reset(0)">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="return reset((5*60)+30)">Kolkata</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation has two pieces of state:

1. `dateString` - the string representation of the time
2. `offset` - the currently chosen time offset

`tick` updates `dateString` repeatedly to capture the passage of time.

`render` renders the `dateString` to the DOM using `requestAnimationFrame`.

```js
const freeze = Object.freeze
const DTF = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', hour12: false })
let state = freeze({ 
  dateString: '00:00:00',
  offset: 0
})

function setOffset(o) {
  clearTimeout(tickId)
  state = freeze({ ...state, offset: o })
  tick()
}

function toDateString(date = new Date) {
  const d = DTF.formatToParts(date)
  return `${d[0].value}:${d[2].value}:${d[4].value}`
}

let tickId = null
function tick() {
  const date = new Date
  date.setHours(date.getHours() + state.offset)
  const dateString = toDateString(date)
  tickId = setTimeout(tick, 16)
  if(dateString !== state.dateString)
    state = freeze({ ...state, dateString })
}

function render(state) {
  document.getElementById('time').innerText = state.dateString
}

let previousState = null
function loop() {
  if(state !== previousState)  {
    previousState = state
    render(state)
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
}

tick()
requestAnimationFrame(loop)
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  background-color: rgba(0,220,220,0);
  transition: background-color .5s ease-out 0s;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: rgba(0,220,220,1);
}

#time {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="london" checked>
<label for="london" onclick="setOffset(0)">London</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="amsterdam">
<label for="amsterdam" onclick="setOffset(1)">Amsterdam</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="new-york">
<label for="new-york" onclick="setOffset(-4)">New York</label>
<div id="time"></div>
```